# Lag Lead Enumerator

Tags: c#, iterator, extension-methods

I had a need to do a look-ahead and look-behind when enumerating though and `IEnumerable`. Here is a classic situation:

```
foreach(var element in anEnumerable)
{
    //I can get at the current element while iterating (obviously)
    //But sometimes I need to "lookahead" to see what the next element is going to be
    ///or "lookbehind" to see what the last element was.
}
```

So I thought I'd see if I could encapsulate the logic to do something like this pseudocode:

```
foreach(var element in anEnumerable.AsSomethingThatLetsMeSeeAheadAndBehind())
{
    element.Current; //the T of whatever anEnumerable<T> was
    element.Lag; //The preceeding T in the enumerable as we enumerate
    element.Lead;  //The next T in the enumerable as we enumerate
    element.Lead(2); //not in this discussion, but it would be neat to look beyond the adjacent element
}
```

The `AsSomethingThatLetsMeSeeAheadAndBehind()` extension method is an attempt to make it simple to generate the wrapper around any enumerable of type `T`, so I built the below implementations of an `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` from scratch, but there are some code smells:

1. Needing two separate extension methods to deal with Value Types and Reference Types. I just could not get it to work any other way (even `ValueType`s must return `null` for *lead* and *lag* outside the enumerable)
2. The `List<object> _history`in the Enumerator and the `MoveNext()` code just feels wrong

This code is a direct copy from Linqpad where It was built. If you copy it and run it, you will see it works as expected. The `.Dump()` in Linqpad is calling a `foreach` under the hood.

Suggestions on improvements?

```
void Main()
{
    var l = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    var p = new List<IEnumerable<int>>() {l.Take(1), l.Take(2), l.Take(3)};
    l.AsLLEStruct().Dump();
    p.AstLLERef().Dump();
}

public static class extns
{
    public static LagLeadEnumerable<Nullable<T>> AsLLEStruct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : struct
    {
        return new LagLeadEnumerable<Nullable<T>>(enumerable.Cast<T?>());
    }

    public static LagLeadEnumerable<T> AstLLERef<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : class
    {
        return new LagLeadEnumerable<T>(enumerable);
    }
}


public class LagLeadEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<ILagLeader<T>>
{
    IEnumerable<T> _enumer;

    public LagLeadEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumer = enumerable;
    }

    public IEnumerator<ILagLeader<T>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new LagLeadEnumerator<T>(_enumer.GetEnumerator());
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class LagLeadEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<LagLeadEnumerator<T>>, ILagLeader<T>
{
    IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    List<object> _history = new List<object>();
    bool _lastMove = false;
    bool _atEnd = false;

    public LagLeadEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        _enumerator = enumerator;
        Init();
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    LagLeadEnumerator<T> IEnumerator<LagLeadEnumerator<T>>.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _enumerator.Dispose();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _history.Add(_enumerator.Current);
        _lastMove = _atEnd;
        if (!_lastMove)
        {
            _atEnd = !_enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        return !(_atEnd & _lastMove);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void Init()
    {
        _history.Clear();
        _enumerator.MoveNext();
        _history.Add(null);
        _history.Add(null);
    }

    public T Lead
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_atEnd)
            {
                return _enumerator.Current;
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public T Lag
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)_history[_history.Count - 2];
        }
    }


    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)_history[_history.Count - 1];
        }
    }

    T ILagLeader<T>.Lead => throw new NotImplementedException();

    T ILagLeader<T>.Lag => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public interface ILagLeader<T>
{
    T Lead { get; }
    T Current { get; }
    T Lag { get; }
}
```

Comment: Could explain the _look-ahead and look-behind_ idea in more detail? Even when looking at the code in LINQPad I still don't get it... and you are also not making it easy to understand with the three letter interface `ILL` ;-| is this any know algorithm? Maybe you could add a link?

Comment: @t3chb0t I'd also like an explanation. But as far as I can see, the idea is that as you go through the enumerator, you keep track of the three most recent items instead of just the 1. In order these are `Lag`, `Current` and `Lead`. So unlike a usual enumerator, `Current` doesn't refer to the head of the enumerator but the one before it. I'm still not sure exactly what happens in the edge cases (beginning and end of list)... Would be nice to see the output from those `Dump`s.

Comment: @BenAaronson I saw the output of all `Dump`s but I'm not feeling like debugging it ;-) Let's hope OP'll provide more info.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I've updated the question, does that help ?

Comment: For the first point you *could* implement your own option type(like nullable) that works for both ref and value types. Of course the `T?` wouldn't be available. This would also allow you to make the history a `List<Maybe<T>>` instead of `List<object>`(where `Maybe` is your own option type, I believe there are some implementations on NuGet). I don't have time right now to provide example code for these, so take these as mere suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Specification

> *even ValueTypes must return null for lead and lag outside the enumerable*

This behavior is in conflict with that of [`IEnumerator.Current`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.current?view=netframework-4.8). The value should be *undefined* if out of bounds.

> Current is **undefined** under any of the following conditions:
>
> - The enumerator is positioned before the first element in the collection, immediately after the enumerator is created. `MoveNext` must
>     be called to advance the enumerator to the first element of the
>     collection before reading the value of `Current`.
> - The last call to `MoveNext` returned `false`, which indicates the end of the collection.
> - The enumerator is invalidated due to changes made in the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements.

What exactly is 'undefined'? Find out with me..

```
int[]a = new int[] {0};
var  e = a.GetEnumerator();
e.MoveNext();
e.MoveNext();

//  System.InvalidOperationException: Enumeration already finished.
Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
```

This means that `lag` and `lead` should also throw an `InvalidOperationException` when out of bounds. So there is no value in differentiating between *value* and *reference* types.

---

#### Alternative 1

What you could do is augment `LagLeadEnumerator<T>` with:

- methods `CanLag()` and `CanLead()`, optionally with overloads that take an offset.
- methods `TryLag()` and `TryLead()`, optionally with overloads that take an offset.
- I also like the names `Previous` and `Next` (as suggested in JanDotNet's answer) as aliases for `Lag(1)` and `Lead(1)`.

---

#### Alternative 2

As an alternative you could use a stream with look-around support. Many compiler generator APIs come with such classes. For instance, [ANTLRInputStream](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRInputStream.html) which provides a method `LA(int i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Its a nice idea.. Sometimes I have exactly that problem.

However, I see some improvements in your implementation:

**Naming**

AsLLEStruct / AsLLERef is not very intuitive. Just take a look at the Enumerable class of the .Net framework and find a name that fits into the naming pattern.

I would call it "EumerateContextAware", "EnumerateWithContext" or something like that...
The object to be return may be called `EnumerationContext` with properties `Current`, `Next`, `Previous`.

**Do not use the enumerator as retund value**

```
AsLLEStruct().ToList().Select(a => a.Current).Dump();
// gives {7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7}
```

Return a new EnumerationContext object that persist its state.